# Executing this query if user has a row in DB, else not

Tags: php

I have a table called `user_bio`, this table has one row, which was inserted manually:

```
id: 1
age: 30
studying: Business
language: English
relationship_status: Single
username: conor
about_me: This is conor's bio.
```

I have a page called `account_settings_bio.php`, from where the logged in user (`$username`) can edit their details. At the moment, when I log in as conor, I can `UPDATE` my data, but say for example I log in as `Alice`, Alice has no row in the database, therefore, I would have to `INSERT` data for her, but it doesn't seem to insert a new row for her.

Here is my approach:

```
if ($update_bio){
            /*************************/
            // need to check if the username has data already in the db, if so, then we update the data, otherwise we insert data.
                $get_bio = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username ='$username'");
                $row_returned = mysqli_num_rows($get_bio);

                if ($row_returned == 1){
                    $update_details_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE user_bio SET studying ='$new_studying', language ='$new_lang', 
                                                                relationship_status = '$new_rel', about_me = '$about_me' WHERE username ='$username'");
                } if ($row_returned == 0) {
                    $insert_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_bio VALUES ('', '$age', '$new_lang','$new_rel', '$username', '$about_me'");
                }
                echo "  <div class='details_updated'>
                            <p> Details updated successfully! </p>
                        </div>";    
            }
```

The `UPDATE` query works fine, when logged in as conor, data does change in the db, its just the `INSERT` which is not working.

Comment: Specify the columns.

Comment: Don't assume your queries are successful. Always check for errors. http://php.net/mysqli_error

Answer (score 0):

The order of the inserted columns is not the same as in the database and there are missing some (`studying`).
To be sure, you could rewrite your insert SQL to be more explicit:

`INSERT INTO user_bio (id, age, studying, language, relationship_status, username, about_me) VALUES (NULL, '$age', '$new_studying', '$new_lang','$new_rel', '$username', '$about_me'"`

Note: why not use `if($row_returned==0){ /* INSERT */ } else { /* UPDATE */ }` instead of a double `if`?

Comment: I have tried an `if else` approach, but it didn't work, so I thought I would just refine the query to be more precise, and it may just work. I have also just see that I missed a variable in the `INSERT`, I have changed it, also tried your more explicit approach, but no new row is being generated in the db?

Comment: What do the returned results (e.g. `$insert_query` and `$update_details_query`) give you? Are they returning errors? Have a look at the error handling in the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php